# SPARK-Read file with multi character delimiter with multiline option

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to read a file which has multi character delimiter with multiline option in spark 3.0.1?

Input file

```
company||street||city
Test1 company||1st street||city1
Test2 company||2nd street||city2
Test3 company||"3rd
 street"||city3
```

```scala
spark.read
        .option("delimiter", "||")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("multiLine", "true")
        .option("inferSchema", "false")
        .csv(transformedFile)
```

On printing the dataframe it shows total records as 4 instead of 3.

```
records count :4
+-------------+
|company      |
+-------------+
|Test1 company|
|Test2 company|
|Test3 company|
|street"      |
+-------------+

+-------------+-----------+-----+
|company      |street     |city |
+-------------+-----------+-----+
|Test1 company|1st street |city1|
|Test2 company|2nd street |city2|
|Test3 company|3rd 
street|city3|
+-------------+-----------+-----+
```

The same works as expected if it is a single character delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the dataframe to make sure that it's read properly:

```
val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "||")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("multiLine", "true")
        .option("inferSchema", "false")
        .csv(transformedFile)

df.cache

df.select("company").show
+-------------+
|      company|
+-------------+
|Test1 company|
|Test2 company|
|Test3 company|
+-------------+

df.count
// 3
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain how exactly "cache" here ensures the file is read properly?

Comment: I suppose spark will go through the whole file once completely when caching. If you don't cache, it will load the file using lazy evaluation, which means it does not go through the whole file, and could cause problems with non-standard file formats

Comment: Hello, I tried this on Databricks with Spark 3.0.1. Unfortunately, it didn't work. any other suggestions ?